# Lightswitch Loop Through Child Records in C#

Tags: c#, parent-child, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have a Lightswitch project which has an order table and an orderlines table. I want to be able to loop thought all the orderlines data relating to the current parent order using code behind in C# (it's to send out an email).

I can't seem to find any references on how to do this. Although I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Numb

Comment: `foreach (var orderLine in this.OrderLinesCollection){ }` from the details screen of the `Orders` set ?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for future references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this from the `Details screen` of the `Orders` set

```
foreach (var orderLine in this.OrderLinesCollection)
{
    //send emails here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Lightswitch exactly works but i do know how C# works i think :)

```
var order = getOrder(id) // just some way to get an order with an collection of orderlines
foreach(var line in order.OrderLines)
{
   //Do your thing here
}
```

I hope this will help?